# Confusion about class loading

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused about when the class actually is loaded by the JVM. I noticed that the class loader will load the class when the class is referenced.

I am using java6 environment and run with -verbose:class for tracking class loading.
For example:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject(); //MyObject.class will be loaded
```

However, in this case

```
// ClassC.java
package com.gogog22510.test;
public class ClassC {}

// ClassB.java
package com.gogog22510.test;
public class ClassB extends ClassC {}

// ClassA.java
package com.gogog22510.test;
public class ClassA {
    public ClassC test() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

when my test program initialize ClassA, it will load all ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC even though I haven't invoked test()

```
// TestClassLoad.java
package com.gogog22510.test;
public class TestClassLoad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize ClassA
        System.out.println("start load ClassA");
        new ClassA();
    }
}
```

> console:
>
> > [Loaded TestClassLoad from file:/.../bin/]
> >     start load ClassA
> >     [Loaded ClassA from file:/C:/.../bin/]
> >     [Loaded ClassC from file:/C:/.../bin/]
> >     [Loaded ClassB from file:/C:/.../bin/]

But if I change the test() method's return type like this:

```
// ClassA.java
package com.gogog22510.test;
public class ClassA {
    public ClassB test() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

ClassLoader will only load ClassA into perm space unless I invoke the test() method.

> console:
>
> > [Loaded TestClassLoad from file:/.../bin/]
> >     start load ClassA
> >     [Loaded ClassA from file:/C:/.../bin/]

Why does the ClassLoader load all three class before I explicitly call the method?

Comment: _it will load all ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC_ How can you tell?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour, only ClassA is being loaded http://ideone.com/Gw9QDU

Comment: This source code is not complete enough to reproduce. What class is main(String[]) in? Are ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC inner classes or separate source files?  What does MyObject have to do with this? When are you saying it'll be loaded in the example you give? It would be helpful to have a precise reproduction case of the behavior you're describing (and as @SotiriosDelimanolis mentions, how you're measuring the behavior you describe).

Comment: @Pshemo - I am able to reproduce this behavior with `java -verbose:class classA` . Java 8

Comment: @Pshemo - The classes might be loaded but not *initialized* so we should not consider execution of static blocks as a criteria in coming to conclusions :)

Comment: For me classes A,B and C are getting loaded in both cases. Next, if I add another class `xyz{}` then it is not being loaded. Will look at byte code and get back

Comment: `Different subclasses of ClassLoader may implement different loading policies. In particular, a class loader may cache binary representations of classes and interfaces, prefetch them based on expected usage, or load a group of related classes together. ` According to this, preloading is fine, so long as all this is hidden from the application, for example any `ClassNotFoundException`s should only be thrown when appropriate and preloaded classes must not be initialised prematurely.

Comment: Also: `The resolution step is optional at the time of initial linkage. An implementation may resolve symbolic references from a class or interface that is being linked very early, even to the point of resolving all symbolic references from the classes and interfaces that are further referenced, recursively. (This resolution may result in errors from these further loading and linking steps.) `

Comment: @biziclop - Better to answer it than comment in chunks :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes, you are right. Loading of class and its initialization are two processes, but since they are very closely related people tend to name them the same and I (maybe wrongly) assumed that OP may also meant initialization. Purpose of my comment was to encourage OP to add more details about his code and how he determined that classes are loaded.

Comment: @TheLostMind I'm not yet 100% certain about how relevant these snippets from the JLS are.

Comment: @Pshemo - `java -verbose:class` would work for him :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes, but I would like to hear it from OP, just to make sure that it is real question, and not some kind of misunderstanding :)

Comment: I think your code to "reference classA" might be relevant to the question, yes?

Comment: Also note that if you are using Java 8, they changed the way classes are loaded, since there is no permGen space anymore.

Comment: The test program is separate class "TestClassLoad" and its only contains the main() method

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I use vmarg "-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading" to trace the class loading

Comment: @Sekkuar I am using java6 tho...

Comment: And the code that "references" the class?

Comment: @Sekkuar I add the complete test class in the post

Comment: Important academic questions. of no use in most cases as your more bothered about instances in memory, and functionality. In web apps at least. my advice if your learning java, move on to other aspects like things in java.utils, making a web project, understanding http, browsers and javascript

Comment: there are three public classes in one code snippet without package statements. if they are in different packages, you'd better specify it.

Comment: @tgkprog you are right, this is a rare case. But it is a simplify version of problem I encountered when my project is using a third-party library which generates codes like ClassA I mentioned in the post, and the package contains lots of ClassB. It cuz me an outOfMemory exception in perm space. I fix this by only loading what I actually needed.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker good suggestion...they are all in same package. I will add it in the post. Thanks

Comment: Why not just give java more memory ? Not the best solution but works as soemtime down the line could access those classes again. also when u do need them, all the classes will be loaded right? need to plan for max perm gen space.

Comment: @tgkprog Since the project is part of a big system that it does have memory settings for perm space. I'll load the rest classes if I need them. Since the class that will cuz the memory issue is the default factory classes which will load 5~6 different implementation of factories and my work around is don't use the default one but implement a my factory which will load the factory I actually use...

Comment: @tgkprog If you run out of memory, it's prudent to investigate why it happened. It could be that the solution is to simply add more memory but it could point to some underlying problem (a leak, typically) that can't be solved by throwing more memory at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it happens during the verification step, to make sure that `ClassC` is a subclass of `ClassB`, for purposes of validating the return type.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9), they say:

> If the method returns a reference type, it must do so using an areturn
>   instruction, and the type of the returned value must be assignment
>   compatible (JLS §5.2) with the return descriptor (§4.3.3) of the
>   method.

See also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.1):

> Verification (§4.10) ensures that the binary representation of a class
>   or interface is structurally correct (§4.9). Verification may cause
>   additional classes and interfaces to be loaded (§5.3) but need not
>   cause them to be verified or prepared.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it. JVM needs to load the ClassA, that includes loading the methods code into the memory; ClassA have a method that returns a ClassC, thus, it loads ClassC; Finally, the method returns an object of ClassB, so ClassB needs to be loaded as well. It doesn't matter if invoke the method or not, the method needs to be already loaded into memory before it can be invoked, so the classloader loads everything every method needs to work. For instance, if he had another method that returned ClassD, both method would have to be available, and ClassD would have to be loaded as well.

Comment: @Sekkuar I think it will happen when you have a type conversion during the method return. It will do the verification mentioned in the post and it required both ClassB and ClassC be ready in the ClassLoader.

Comment: @Vlad I only went through the Linking and Loading part for the article previously and didn't see that part tho...Thanks for the answer :)